# SonarQube JIRA plugin - how to configure authorization data and what permissions a user needs?

Tags: sonarqube, integration, jira

http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/JIRA+Plugin

In the above instruction: set the `sonar.jira.url`, `sonar.jira.login.secured` and `sonar.jira.password.secured` properties.

1. It's a JIRA user or SonarQube user, or both?
2. What kind of permission this user needs?

[image: configuration]

Answer (score 1):

1. Jira user
2. Permissions:

   - view project
   - view issues
   - create issue

`SOAP base URL` value is relative to `Server URL` so you can remove the entered value.

Comment: Use the JIRA id, and removed SOAP Base URL, it's working now. Thanks a lot.

Comment: You're welcome. Please accept the answer as it solve your problem :-)

Comment: Sorry, one more problem: the link in JIRA issue is like this: Check it on Sonar: http://localhost:9000/issue/show/b2f46c9d-cabd-4acd-99bf-5021969dcceb, how can I use the right SonarQube hostname?

Comment: You should ask a new question. Fast help: SonarQube Web GUI -> Settings -> General -> Server base URL.

Comment: SonarQube doesn't support jira 7.x now; there's some workaround for jira 7.x with new plugin (unofficial) 1.3. Do we need to install anything or any changes at Jira 7 side?

Comment: I don't know. Jira won't be supported any more by SonarQube team. Reason: http://www.sonarqube.org/stop-planning-fix-the-leak/