# SonarQube cannot connect to JIRA 7 with REST API

Tags: continuous-integration, sonarqube, jira, devops

I am trying to connect my SonarQube installation to JIRA 7.0.2 for issue linking. I have filled the configuration fields (Files attached), but I get the error, impossible to connect to JIRA server. Both JIRA and SonarQube are on the same server.

[image]

Comment: Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33046953/sonarqube-jira-plugin-how-to-configure-authorization-data-and-what-permissions/

Comment: @agabrys I am using Jira 7.0.2 and rest API calls rather than Soap calls. Is that the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The [JIRA Plugin](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/JIRA+Plugin) is not compatible with JIRA 7 or newer (does not support REST).

From [SonarQube Wiki](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/JIRA+Plugin#JIRAPlugin-Requirements):

- Jira 3.x supported by 1.0, 1.1, 1.2
- Jira 4.x supported by 1.0, 1.1, 1.2
- Jira 5.x supported by 1.0, 1.1, 1.2
- Jira 6.x supported by 1.2

There is an issue about support REST API in [tracking system](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-jira/issues/3).

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/Miovision/sonar-jira. It's working with JIRA 7.0

Copy the jar file "SonarInstallation\extensions\plugins"

Don't forget to remove the old one. "1.2"

Comment: opps, downgrading sonar or jira to 6.0 is not a solution. We need a new solution development for new ones..