# SonarQube connection to JIRA 7

Tags: rest, soap, sonarqube

**Can some one please help me connecting to JIRA 7 in SonarQube JIRA plugin ?**

**After giving correct inputs** for 
server url, username, password, JIRA Project key
Its not working and show error as "Impossible to connect to the JIRA server ".
sonar log also does not show any error related to this.

**SOAP base url** in JIRA plugin setting in SonarQube is blank and also accessing http://{my jira url}/rpc/soap/jirasoapservice-v2 give 404 error.
even though its enabled in my JIRA 7.

**In below SonarQube page**, it seems its last update is in December related to version descriptions.
http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/JIRA+Plugin#JIRAPlugin-Requirements
http://docs.sonarqube.org/pages/diffpagesbyversion.action?pageId=1442016&selectedPageVersions=101&selectedPageVersions=102

**Searching on Google finding few post where it says** 
**"The JIRA Plugin is not compatible with JIRA 7 or newer."**
[SonarQube cannot connect to JIRA 7 with REST API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33903497/sonarqube-cannot-connect-to-jira-7-with-rest-api)

**"Jira SOAP API has been removed in Jira 7"**
https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-jira/issues/3

So please let me know if anyone khows how to connect to JIRA 7 in SonarQube JIRA plugin.

My SonarQube verion is 5.2 and also checked with 5.4.
SonarQUbe JIRA plugin version is 1.2.
My JIRA version is  7.2.0-OD-05-030.

Thanks,
Sandeep

Comment: You may want to have a look at this blog article : http://www.sonarqube.org/stop-planning-fix-the-leak/ which explains that linking Jira and SonarQube is maybe not the best idea (at a functional level).

Comment: @benzonico, you are saying that it may not be the best idea, does it mean that its possible to connect to jira? If yes, can you please help me on how to do that for the versions I mentioned with which I am getting the error/ issue?

Answer (score 0):

You found out the answer already: Jira Plugin is not compatible with Jira 7. There is no workaround/fix, otherwise it would already be mentioned in the related [GitHub issue](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-jira/issues/3).

Note that the underlying functionality of linking SonarQube issues to 3rd-party ticketing systems is being dropped altogether ([SONAR-6717](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONAR-6717)). Equivalent grouping/planning of issues can be done using tags and filters, see this [blog post](http://www.sonarqube.org/stop-planning-fix-the-leak/) for more details.

Comment: Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Also i am still wondering on why the JIRA plugin is available to download in SonarQube and why the options available to use it if it is dropped by SonarQube. any comments/idea on this ?