# SonarQube Perforce Plugin 1.2 on Sonar 5.2 login error, no report

Tags: plugins, sonarqube, perforce

We got following issue when we test SonarQube 5.2. Perforce plugin starts to behave incorrectly. It prints error in log:

```
[07:30:30]W: [] [ERROR] Perforce password (P4PASSWD) invalid or unset.
[07:30:30] : [] [DEBUG] Perforce password (P4PASSWD) invalid or unset.
```

Even if I set -X for Maven I did not get more details why it prints this error.

Only difference it that it uses SonarQube 5.2. On SonarQube 5.1.2 it works fine. Also it looks like upload passes and no report is shows on SonarQube server UI.

Only message I see on server log is:

```
12:32:31 ERROR web[o.s.s.c.t.CeWorkerRunnableImpl] Executed task | project=<prjkey>
          | id=AVFYYUYrsGEyA8a-XeTJ | time=2231ms
```

again without any details even if I set DEBUG log level.

Secondary problem is that I tried to register to JIRA for SonarQube but I am not able to create new issue. I can only view existing issues. So only option is to ask here.

Comment: You should not ask two question in one post (`secondary problem`). You can read more about SonarQube & JIRA authorization in this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33046953/sonarqube-jira-plugin-how-to-configure-authorization-data-and-what-permissions

Answer (score 0):

[P4PASSWD](https://www.perforce.com/perforce/r15.1/manuals/cmdref/P4PASSWD.html) is a variable which is supposed to contains the password of the current user.

Check if you have entered it somewhere in the plugin configuration. You can also try to set it up manually by calling `p4 set P4PASSWD=XXX`. This is not the cleanest solution but it might be a temporary workaround.